# JavaScript's time zones as a way to locate a user's country

Tags: javascript, geolocation, timezone

I need to determine a user's country, and it doesn't need to be super accurate (getting it right 90% of the time is probably enough). I realized the time zone returned by JavaScript could work.

Example:

`console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone);`

Will return `America/Toronto` or `America/New_York`, which can help me differentiate a Canadian from an American.

Sure I understand this is based on the user’s preferences, not its real location. But is there a huge pitfall I'm not seeing right now using this technic?

Comment: Well it does not mean the user will use the right timezone, but if you want to take the risk you can do it.

Comment: @epascarello Fair point : what's % of users has the right timeZone set on their devices? But I feel it most be high, since your clock wouldn't be on the right time otherwise and most OS can set it automatically nowadays.

Comment: I doubt anyone knows the numbers....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, turns out it depends on the scenario (was predictable). For my scenarios, American get the right Timezone 95%+ of the time, while Canadian get it 90%+.

The way to test this out was to save the user's JS timezone in our Google Analytics, and then compare it to their location.

So your mileage may vary, but for my use case, this was more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this without resorting to IP-to-location services, the following code utilizes the `moment-timezone` library for mapping time zones to countries. The function `getCountryByTimeZone` iterates through a list of countries and checks if the provided time zone is associated with any country. If a match is found, it uses `Intl.DisplayNames` to retrieve the full country name; otherwise, it returns the original time zone.

```js
// Import the moment-timezone library
const moment = require('moment-timezone');

/**
 * Get the user's country based on their time zone.
 * @param {string} userTimeZone - The user's time zone.
 * @returns {string} The user's country or the original time zone if not found.
 */
function getCountryByTimeZone(userTimeZone) {
  // Get a list of countries from moment-timezone
  const countries = moment.tz.countries();

  // Iterate through the countries and check if the time zone is associated with any country
  for (const country of countries) {
    const timeZones = moment.tz.zonesForCountry(country);

    if (timeZones.includes(userTimeZone)) {
      // Use Intl.DisplayNames to get the full country name
      const countryName = new Intl.DisplayNames(['en'], { type: 'region' }).of(country);
      return countryName;
    }
  }

  // Return the original time zone if no matching country is found
  return userTimeZone;
}

// Example usage
const userTimeZone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
const userCountry = getCountryByTimeZone(userTimeZone);
console.log('User country based on time zone:', userCountry);
```

---

#### Usage:

- Copy and paste the provided code into your JavaScript environment.
- Call the getCountryByTimeZone function with the user's time zone to retrieve the user's country.
- The function returns either the matching country or the original time zone if no match is found.

#### Note:

- Make sure to have the moment-timezone library installed in your project.
- The accuracy of the result depends on the completeness and accuracy of the time zone data provided by the library.